# Flask-dance Google oauth setup issue with pythonanywhere

Tags: google-signin, pythonanywhere, flask-dance

I am trying to set up Google login for my webapp with Flask-dance. The problem is with setting the 'Authorized redirect uri' in the Google Developer's console as `https://moneycare.pythonanywhere.com/google/authorized`. I get an error 'Invalid Redirect: must use a domain that is a valid top private domain'. This is happening only with PythonAnywhere domain. If switch the url with something like `https://moneycare.herokuapp.com/google/authorized` then the error does not appear.

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks.